# Android php login system

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

This is my first post . 
I am making android php login system, Basically i am making hybrid app . So i will be calling php page in the android app . so wht i want to do is tht using android screen and php page finger print login system .At the php side i have an idea of everything but i dont knw to capture android screen and send image finger print image to server .
Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope you are using "finger print" in some sort of hash-footprint kinda way, because I don't think you can actually scan your finger-print on the screen of a default touchscreen.

Comment: Thanks . i think u r rite , but if you see the android login system using finger print then it seems tht there can be possibility . Thanks

Comment: You cannot scan a fingerprint from a touchscreen. The only Android device that can detect 10 finger tips at once is the upcoming Xoom, AFAIK the Galaxy S and Tab are restricted to four tips and thats the best ATM. There is no capacity for finer or smaller touches. If this were possible, the technology wouldn't be accepted and/or we would unlock our phones with our fingerprints :)

Answer (score 0):

Your can capture images using the camera only, no way to acquire data from the screen itself. So I guess you need to make your system login using face recognition. However this will be easy to fake (take a picture of an existing photo of your president and log on his account)...

Other than this, to send an image or more generally data to a server using HTTP, have a look at the HttpClient class from Apache.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but as u see the android finger login system , i want to develop the same application for web .

Comment: Sorry but you'll find out the hard way that **TRUE** finger print scanning is not possible on Android phones. Some tricks could be used to fake it though. Some info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934184/android-fingerprint-scanner-application