# Add fingerPrint lock to app

Tags: android, fingerprint

I am creating a Applock app. Which will support pattern,PIN,finger Print methods of securing apps.I am stuck at fingerprint part.I searched on Google But all i found was about using finger print sensor for **fingerPrint Authentication**. Some help that i found is this.
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial

[How to Integrate fingerprint lock in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119695/how-to-integrate-fingerprint-lock-in-android)

http://joerichard.net/android/android-fingerprint-example/

Is there any way by that i can use **phone screen for scanning my fingerprint**.If My phone dont have sensor on back(or front) of my phone.

Something like this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sparrow.peter.applockapplicationlocker&hl=en

Comment: So you want to replace the fingerprint sensor with an image recognition software built in your app?

Comment: yes but how can i do that

Comment: It is kinda impossible, you don't ever reach the necessary image resolution in a camera. fingerprints are too elaborated. That's exactly why you can not take a picture of your thumb and unlock your phone by showing it. You can as alternative to the thumbs use the facial recognition by camera